# TZD database missing transitions?

Tags: nodatime

I'm using version 'TZDB: 2018c (mapping: 13290)' of the TZD db however when I ask for Pacific/Auckland timezone information using either

```
VTimeZone.FromTzId(tzdbId);
```

or

```
VTimeZone.FromTzId(tzdbId, earliestDateTimeToSupport, true);
```

If I use 2008-01-01 as earliestDateTimeToSupport I'll get the current daylight saving details and recurrence rules. If however I use any date after that or NO date I'll get UTC -11 (WHEN was that rule last in play??? not while I've been alive.) and the recurrence rule looks all wrong. Can anyone advise if this is the DB or something I'm likely to be doing?

Australia/Sydney seems to behave properly... they've had a timezone change during 2008 and that rule comes through... and I'm not going to test them all but I think this is just a fault with NZDST for dates post (ish) 2009-1-1.

Comment: Oh, currently the rules are UTC+13 for DST. So the +11 is just weird. I'm guessing it's defaulting to some very old rule, as if the rule change that happened sometime in the 2000's has an end date with no new rule following it, thus weird rules.

Comment: That is `VTimeZone`? It would help if you'd provide a [mcve] rather than just a single line that refers to a type that isn't in Noda Time.

Comment: Using just Noda Time, it looks fine for me: https://gist.github.com/jskeet/d6723413a01bf0dc4a83066a66cc1c16 shows alternating between +12 and +13, which fits with https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/master/australasia

Comment: My appologise this might be an ical.net issue. The method is at line 58 on https://github.com/rianjs/ical.net/blob/master/v2/ical.NET/Components/VTimeZone.cs

Comment: I wouldn't like to guess at exactly what that's doing. You might want to file a GitHub issue with a [mcve].

Comment: I'll close this off with a comment once I hear back from the maintainers of that package. At first glance it appears to be a bug not caught during testing, potentially due to testing using northern hemisphere timezones (where DST rolls over mid year, not on Jan-1) and not including southern hemispheres. Lets wait and see so I can close this off with an answer in-case anyone else mistakenly thinks it's the DB files.